# how to filter by wildcard with aws java sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using aws java sdk to describe ec2 instances with a request:

```
new DescribeInstanceRequest().withFilters(new Filter("tag:TagKey", "expectedTagValue"));
```

How can I use wildcard?

```
new DescribeInstanceRequest().withFilters(new Filter("tag:TagKey", "expectedTag*"));
```

And how I can I filter all instances have the filter? for example:

```
new DescribeInstanceRequest().withFilters(new Filter(tagExist("tag:TagKey")));
```

Above are just what I have in mind, what is the correct way to do so?

Comment: The documentation says the tag-key filter would check whether a tag exists;  I don't see any way to do wildcard searches. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
new Filter().withName("tag-key").withValues(tagName);
```

where `tagName`is the tag by which you want to filter. I have used this to filter snapshots, should work for instances as well.

Comment: He wants to filter using a wildcard, this solution will not work